# Is it possible to move between the various fifth bases of Fuji?

Tags: japan, hiking, mountain-climbing, mount-fuji

For an upcoming trip to Fuji, I plan to cycle to the fifth base, probably using the Fuji-Subaru line from Fujiyoshida. However, my friends plan to use one of the other trails. Assuming I have enough of an headstart over them, is it possible for me to move to the base they'll use and meet up with them?

They also plan to descend by a different trail than the one used for ascending, so I'd have to move between fifth bases twice, via different combinations each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not really**.  Fuji is, surprise surprise, a large mountain and the 5th bases are not connected.  However, depending on which trails you take, you may be able to meet halfway through since some of them merge before the summit:

[image]

(courtesy [Japan Guide](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e6901.html))